# Javascript - formular - nested dynamic appendchild functions

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic, appendchild

I have a form which changes the inputfields depending on a radio-button.

for text there appears a textbox
for textarea there appear additional 2 fields for cols And rows
for select, checkbox and radio there appear additional fields with appendchild

have a look here:
http://joomla.byethost16.com/php.php

Now what i want is to let the user add more params, param2, param3, etc.

Unfortunately i made the js functions that trigger the fields according to the radio-button like this

```
    function textarea(){    
if (document.getElementById('option2').checked = true){
    document.getElementById('feld').style.display = '';
        document.getElementById('feld2').style.display = '';
        document.getElementById('feld4').style.display = 'none';
}}
```

So that means i have no dynamics in my form since the id in this function is not yet dynamic and onclick will trigger anything or only always the first param1.

all params should be like this but somehow increasing numbers and the Js-function for the radio should take them too

```
    <td>Param_1</td>
<td><p>
<input type="radio" onclick='text()' name="option0" id="option0" value="text" checked="yes">text
<input type="radio" onclick='spacer()' name="option0" id="option1" value="spacer">spacer
<input type="radio" onclick='textarea()' name="option0" id="option2" value="textarea">textarea
<input type="radio" onclick='selecta()' name="option0" id="option3" value="select">select
<input type="radio" onclick='radio()' name="option0" id="option4" value="radio">radio
<input type="radio" onclick='checkbox()' name="option0" id="option5" value="checkbox">checkbox</br>
<input type="hidden" name="fields" value="1" id="fields"  />

<div id="feld">
Name <input type="text" name="param1" id="param1" size="40" maxlength="40">
Default<input type="text" name="paramdef1" id="paramdef1" size="40" maxlength="40">
<div id="feld4" style="display:none;">
<input type="text" name="param11" size="40" value="value1" style="display: inline">
<a href=# onclick='add(1)'>add</a>  <a href=# onclick='reset()'>reset</a></div>
</div>

<div id="feld2" style="display:none;">
Columns<input type="text" name="cols1" size="20" maxlength="40">Rows<input type="text" name="rows1" size="20" maxlength="40"></div>


</td>
</tr>
```

How do i do that my form gets dynamically (like i did the "add/reset" at checkboxes) and people can add more params? 
For the complete code please go here and view source:
http://joomla.byethost16.com/php.php

thx so much for help on this

Comment: what is param 2? is it a list of textboxes just like param 1 that users can keeping adding to? how does param 2 relate to the other form controls - text, textarea, select, radio, and checkbox?

Comment: param2,3... is a copy/appendchild of param1. but i dont know how to make the functions (text,textarea,select,...) dynamical that they can be used for the following params too (param2,param3,..). thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by using $(this) with a "click" bind to each class which sits on the buttons.

another solution would be to use a plugin, for example http://www.mdelrosso.com/sheepit/index.php?lng=en_GB which is very good but relys on a certain structure (you have to define an index at the form, which has to be resorted in processing under most cases since some index_vars can be skipped userwise.)